# HTML email template framework supporting both mobile and web layouts

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I need to create html email blast which would look different in layout if opened on web vs mobile phone. All the sources say that I should use inline CSS and tables for this because email clients like gmail are very strict on external css and resources. How would one go on designing this ?

Will 960 gs gris system be helpful here ? Has any used it to design email templates ?

Thanks,
Ved

Answer (score 0):

I helped a client of [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) create an email template that works well with the desktop and mobile. Here are some things to keep in mind when creating the layout of your email:

- Emails are generally kept to 600px in width for best compatibility across the board
- Try not to make it image heavy as that makes it very hard to scale for thinner widths (phones!)
- Try your best to align everything to the left and not throw too many elements on a single line

It's a bit fickle and I had the best experience by removing as many images as I could and reducing the size of everything to at most 300px wide (fit on my iPhone) and continuously tested it by sending it to my iPhone.

I like to think that simpler is better if you want it to be visible on both web and mobile.

Comment: Did you use media query to detect different screen size ? Did you have two diff. layout for mobile and web and controlled them via inline css or did you just let the viewport do the trick and used same layout for both ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) for designing your email. Its a css3 framework to create email templates.